# python , selenium. How I can set a list in localstorage?

Tags: python, selenium

Hello I have a question about my problem:

my code:

```
driver.execute_script("window.localStorage.setItem('myapi','" +str(testmy.accessApi())+ "');")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently executing this:

```
>>> print("window.localStorage.setItem('myapi','" +str(["test1", "test2", "test3"])+ "');")
window.localStorage.setItem('myapi','['test1', 'test2', 'test3']');
```

Take a look at the quotes, this causes the SyntaxError.

localStorage stores only strings anyway. So pass a JSON-string directly:

```
>>> import json
>>> print("window.localStorage.setItem('myapi','" +json.dumps(["test1", "test2", "test3"])+ "');")
window.localStorage.setItem('myapi','["test1", "test2", "test3"]');
```